# How to run window.stop after certain time in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to web scrap a site but the problem with that site is this, content in the site load in 1s but the loader in the navbar kept loading for 30 to 1min so my puppeteer scrapper kept waiting for the loader in the navbar to stop?
Is there any way to run `window.stop()` after a certain timeout

[GITHUB](https://github.com/vakhariaheet/fanfic2book_socket/blob/main/src/Web%20Scrappers/Wattpad/Wattpad.ts)

```js
    const checkBook = async () => {
        await page.goto(`https://wattpad.com/story/${bookid}`, {
            waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
        });
        const is404 = await page.$('#story-404-wrapper');
        if (is404) {
            socket.emit('error', {
                message: 'Story not found',
            });
            await browser.close();
            return {
                error: true,
            };
        }
        storyLastUpdated = await page
            .$eval(
                '.table-of-contents__last-updated strong',
                (ele: any) => ele.textContent,
            )
            .then((date: string) => getDate(date));
    };
```

Comment: Please detail out the point of failure in this quite lengthy linked code. You should include the bit in question in the answer, instead of linking it only.

Comment: I have added the code snippet here `page.goto` wait for 30-40s(because Wattpad loader in navbar kept loading) but the content gets loaded in 1s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar approach to Marcel's answer. The following will do the job:

```js
page.goto(url)
await page.waitForTimeout(1000)
await page.evaluate(() => window.stop())
// your scraper script goes here
await browser.close()
```

Notes:

- [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.1.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) is NOT awaited, so you save time compared to waiting until `DOMContentLoaded` or `Load` events...
- ...if the `goto` was not awaited you need to make sure your script can start the work with the DOM. You can either use [`page.waitForTimeout()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.1.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitfortimeoutmilliseconds) or [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.1.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options).
- you have to execute `window.stop()` within [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.1.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) so you can avoid this kind of error: `Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!`

Answer (score 1):

You could strip the

```
 waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
```

in favor of a timeout as documented here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.1.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options

or set the timeout to zero and instead use one of the `page.waitFor...` like this

```
await page.waitForTimeout(30000);
```